# Get path for in firebase after pushing onto a list

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am saving some user information into the firebase database. I also want to retrieve the path of it after it has been saved successfully. I am able to do it fine, however,  I am confused about the data that I got back as shown below.

[image: screenshot]

So if I want to get the path, I have to run

```
data.path.o
```

Why is this format so weird? I see U, Nc, m, path, Y o. Are they suppose to look like that or am I missing something?

I am using angular 2 + angularfire2 with the following code

```
  saveUserToFirebase(user: User): firebase.database.ThenableReference {
    const userRef = this.af.database.list('/users/' + user.company);
    return userRef.push(user)
  }

this.databaseService.saveUserToFirebase(user)
    .then( data => {
        console.log('User saved to firebase databse with path', data); 
        console.log('User saved to firebase databse with path1', data.path); 
        console.log('User saved to firebase databse with path2', data.path.o); 

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        this.isLoading = false;
    }, error => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log("Error asjf0e", error);
    })
```

Comment: What you're returning from `saveUserToFirebase` is a `ThenableReference`, which is reference to a location in the database. I don't seen anything weird about it, but that may be because I've been using them for a while. What did you expect to see when you log the return value from `saveUserToFirebase`?

Comment: Thanks Frank. Normally when I look at returned object, I expect meaningful key value pairs such as valid : true, status: 404...etc. So I was abit surprised when I see these "seems to be random" alphabets (ca:Nb; fd:0..etc). But it all makes sense now. Out of curiosity, can I reliably use data.path.o[0] , data.path.o[1], data.path.o[2] or would it change to something like data.path.K[0] in time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're returning from `saveUserToFirebase` is a `ThenableReference`, which is reference to a location in the database. A reference doesn't contain the actual data, it is just a pointed to the location.

To get the full URL from a reference, call `toString` on it:

```
this.databaseService.saveUserToFirebase(user)
    .then( ref => {
        console.log('User saved to firebase database with URL', ref.toString()); 

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        this.isLoading = false;
    }, error => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log("Error asjf0e", error);
    })
```

To get just the absolute path (without the domain), you can use string manipulation:

```
var path = ref.toString().substring(ref.root.toString().length);
```